# Opening multiple bat files with one bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, jar, cmd, directory

I have 3 folders:

- Folder1
- Folder2
- Folder3

Each folder has its own start.bat (Folder1/Start.bat,etc..)
I want to make a file, in the folder where the files are listed
The file will open and run each .bat file in a separate window/command prompt
So Folder1's bat file makes a new window and loads
Then folder2. They wont all open in one window.

How would I do this?
I got this:

```
cd C:\Users\Jackson\Desktop\MAIN FOLDER\Folder1
java -Xmx512M Start.bat
```

Even better would be if I could run multiple jars in there own windows with 1 .bat
Like if I had

- Folder1/Jar1.jar
- Folder2/Jar2.jar
- etc...

And I open each one in a seperate window (minecraft console stuff...)

If I'm confusing please tell me if you need me to explain it better. I prefer using the jar files directly instead of opening the bat files.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `START` command with the /B option to suppress the new windows. e.g. NB the double quotes are technically an optional window title but it's better to provide them.

```
START /B "" Java.exe blabla2.jar
START /B "" Java.exe blabal2.jar
...
```

Comment: Okay, so I have the main "starting file" in \bungee\ and I have the minecraft console server thing in \bungee\lobby\ as spigot.jar. The code to run that is `java -Xmx512M -jar spigot.jar` and that works

Comment: but If I put that code in the main file it doesn't work.

Comment: you need to provide the fully qualified path to spigot.jar, or else you need to `cd  lobby` and then run `java -Xmx512M -jar spigot.jar`